# Fired mv wordpress /* ./ while in /var/www

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, vps, mv

I don't why that happened but I was in /var/www and I fired the command

```
mv wordpress /* ./
```

And now I'm not able to access my server via ssh, rdp or teamviewer. I really gotta fix it. What should I do (If I get SSH access somehow)? And can anyone tell what the hell I did? I mean what directories have gone where or whatever.

Is there any way to recover this?

Your help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, it would have given an error that `wordpress and ./wordpress are the same file` Next, it moved the contents of `/` into the current working directory which is `/var/www`. That's why nothing works. You can try to go into single user mode and move the data from `/var/www` back into root with the command `/var/www/usr/bin/mv` /var/www/data__that_should_be_in_root /` but that's not guaranteed to work due to system libraries not being in their proper places and could end up doing more harm than good. I only hope that you have a working backup of your system.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. I am doing the same. Still in process, hope it works. And I wish I had a backup. Do you have an idea about how these whole dedicated servers are backed up? (Apart from purchasing backups from the provider I purchased the Dedicated server from)